# React native alphabets fast scroll

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have this react native app, where the users can choose a country.

How can I press on one of the alphabets and press also other alphabets by moving my finger ? I don't want the full process like in the image bellow, but only the pressing process

When I press on "A" for example, and move my finger to "B" and "C" only "A" is being pressed, not the other alphabets

I want exactly this behavior, as in this image

[image]

I spent a week trying to make this work.

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal

Comment: I didn't, since I only need the alphabet component not all the country stuff module, (even, I only need to accomplish the pressing behavior )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and implement these repositories on GitHub

1- [react-native-section-alphabet](https://github.com/CofferHub/react-native-section-alphabet)

2- [react-native-alphabet-flat-list](https://github.com/yoonzm/react-native-alphabet-flat-list#readme)

3- [react-native-alphabetflatlist](https://github.com/ayushnawani/react-native-alphabetflatlist)

Comment: All these repos need much tweaks to make them workable (tried with expo). Rather you can create it on your own using React <SectionList> and 'absolute positioning' the Alphabets.